# Do While loop is not working?

Tags: c++

in my program. my do-while loop is not working and I have no idea why. All i wanted the do-while loop to do is to alleviate the need for the user to re-run the program when he wants to enter another number.

Comment: What's going wrong? Is it not compiling? Is it not doing what you expect?

Comment: Since it's homework I'll give you a couple of hints.  Don't declare a second runagain string inside the loop.  The one you declared above is fine.  Try printing out what the string contains after you input 'run again'.  You'll notice that cin stops at whitespace.  Look at getline instead.

Comment: What if a user enters `RUN again`???

Answer (score 1):

You declare the `string runagain;` twice in your main loop which is unnecessary. Also `double tester` should be declared in `squarerootfinder` function as you don't use it anywhere else in the program.

`cin` ignores whitespace you should look into the getline function instead. This [link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/getline/) provides an example of how to use it. Using `cin` here is the source of the problem. You can test this by simply adding the line:

```
cout<<runagain;
```

Directly after `cin>>runagain;`.

In this code:

```
 cout << "Enter a whole number to find the square root of it \n";
 cin >> number;
 divisor = number;
 squareroot = squarerootfinder(number, divisor);
```

You set `divisor=number;` then call `squarerootfinder` but instead of using divisor why not just do it like this:

```
 cout << "Enter a whole number to find the square root of it \n";
 cin >> number;
 squareroot = squarerootfinder(number, number);
```

Because `divisor` and `number` are equal after all.

Answer (score -1):

**Try this :**

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

double tester;
using namespace std;

void stoupper (std::string& s)
{
     std::string::iterator i = s.begin();
     std::string::iterator end = s.end();

     while (i != end) {
          *i = std::toupper((unsigned char)*i);
          ++i;
     }
}

double squarerootfinder (double number, double divisor){
     tester = (number / (divisor * divisor));

     if (divisor == 1) {
          return 1;
     }
     else {
          if (tester != (int)tester) divisor = squarerootfinder(number, divisor - 1);
     }

     return divisor;
}

int main() {
     string runagain;
     double number, divisor, squareroot, insidepart;

     do {    
          cout << "Enter a whole number to find the square root of it \n";
          cin >> number;

          divisor = number;
          squareroot = squarerootfinder(number, divisor);
          insidepart = number / (squareroot * squareroot);

          if (insidepart != 1) {
               cout << squareroot << (char)251 << insidepart;
               cout << endl;
          }
          else {
               cout << squareroot << endl;                  
          }

          cout << "written by Arpan Gupta! \n";
          cout << "Enter run again to run the program again. \n";
          cin >> runagain;

          stoupper(runagain);

     } while (runagain == "RUN AGAIN");    

     return 0;
}
```

---

The idea is to try and check any variation of "RUN aGAiN" the user may input (regardless of whether it is all **uppercase/lowercase** or whatever... most likely that's where your issue lies...)

OK, and I cleaned up your code a bit... :-)

---

EDIT : And, yep : absolutely NO reason to re-declare `runagain` within your `do { } while()` loop.